Can siphons improve the efficiency of hydroelectric dams?
Suppose we have built a hydroelectric dam where the water inlet is 100m above the outlet. We can now use the gravitational potential of the water to spin a turbine. However, suppose we install a siphon at the inlet which goes up 10m (let's assume 10m is the maximum water siphon height) before going down. After initially starting the siphon this means the water will flow by itself, downwards for 110m.

Would this improve the efficiency of the turbine at the bottom due to having 110m instead of 100m worth of water pressure and acceleration?

If yes, what is actually doing the extra work in this scenario? I've been taught siphons work due to the atmospheric pressure pushing against the otherwise created vacuum, but it feels wrong that one would be able to extract work purely from being in a high-pressure environment.

If yes, could this be applied multiple times? E.g. instead of having one 110m downwards shaft could we have 10 stages, each stage's output 10m lower than its inlet, each stage with a siphon at its inlet? In total the water would fall 10 $\cdot$ 20m = 200m.


My intuition says that the answer to #2 is that no extra work is being done, the water going down pulls the water going up with it, like a chain, with the atmospheric pressure just ensuring the chain does not break into a vacuum. Which would make the answer to #1 and #3 both no. Is that correct?

No, you cannot gain any efficiency.
Remember the bernoulli equation:
$P_1 + \frac12\rho v_1^2 + \rho gh_1 = P_2 + \frac12\rho v_2^2 + \rho gh_2$
If you have water at rest at $P_{atm}$ on the top, and water flowing out also at  $P_{atm}$ at the bottom, then you get the classical result in which the output velocity is only a function of $\Delta h$.
However, at the siphon's top you have both a pressure lower than  $P_{atm}$ and also a small speed. The result is that you cannot get a larger velocity at the bottom. Actually, assuming no losses due to friction, so it keeps the same velocity ($v_{exit} = \sqrt{2gh}$) at the bottom, you can calculate the maximum height that a siphon could in principle have, which happens when $P=0$ at the peak of the siphon.
In practice though, the limit is actually smaller, and it happens when  the pressure at the top of the siphon falls below the vapour pressure of water causing water to boil breaking the column.
